# How to use a third-party API inside next/api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js, openweathermap

I am new to NEXTJS and creating a weather application .I am using a `openweather api` but how can I use it inside the `next/api`. I had tried by creating a file `today.js` inside `next/api` and wrote the code it in this way but I am unable to get data in console ?

**today.js**

```
const apikey = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY_1;
const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Bhopal&appid=${apikey}`;

const fecthInfo = async() => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json() ;
    return data;
}
export default function handler(req, res) {
    const result = fecthInfo();
    console.log(result)
    res.status(200).json(result)
  }
```

Can you tell the mistake I am doing , or I have to simply use the `fetch` method in any component like in reactJS.

Comment: What you are trying to do? Use API route to call it? Or you like to use this data on front-end side?

Comment: I am trying to use this data in frontend. Can I make use of next/api?

Comment: Yes, you can. How are you calling the API route from the client-side? Note that the `console.log` you have in the API route will log the output to the terminal where you started your dev server, not the browser's console.

Comment: So basically I want to send the input from the client as `city` and then getting the values.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of fetching data from a remote api inside the api route. I suggest to use the getServerSideProps() in the route page directly so you have to fetch the data just once.

You pass the requested data through props to the Test component.

```
const Test= function({data}){
 console.log(data)
 return <div></div>
}



export default async function 
getServerSideProps(){
const response = await fetch(url);
const data = await response.json();
 return {
  props:{data}
 }
}

 export default Test;
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing an async/await. This should work:

```
const apikey = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY_1;
const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Bhopal&appid=${apikey}`;

const fetchInfo = async() => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
};

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const result = await fetchInfo();
    console.log(result);
    res.status(200).json(result);
}
```